# .NET Windows Service from dll

Tags: .net, windows-services, class-library

I have a Windows Service and Service Installer inside of a .NET class library (not an exe).

Once the service is installed via installutil, when trying to start, I get the error

```
Windows could not start the xxx service on Local Computer  
Error 193: 0xc1
```

In googling I found that this error might be due to the fact that my service is part of a dll, not an exe. Could this be the problem? If so, how can I resolve the issue? If not, what else could be the problem.

Comment: If it is the problem, you'd just need to create a console application, rather than a dll... and either link to the dll, or move your code across.

Comment: True but I'd rather not do that...

Comment: A Windows NT service needs to be an executable - I don't think there's any way around this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VS.NET go to New Project/Windows/Windows Service, overwrite the service and install classes with your own. Then you can use installutil on the compiled exe file. There is no way you can install a windows service from a .dll