# Impossible to create windows service via DLL?

Tags: c#, windows-services

Ive written a windows service in **DLL** project. ( c#)

everything is fine with code and also InstallUtil is fine :

[image]

How every when I start it - via services.msc - it tells me

[image]

why is that ? Must I use EXE file (EXE project)?

I dont need the benefits of the exe file.

I just need to activate my dll as service

possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Windows Service from dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362514/net-windows-service-from-dll)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Must I use EXE file (EXE project)?

Yes. Every Windows process starts by loading an exe, then its dependencies and then executing the entry point of the exe.

If you have a suitable entry point in your dll (essentially a `Main`) then a simple exe that just calls that entry point would be sufficient.

Comment: So Can i FAKE it by adding Main entry in the dll file ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir No. (Or at least not in any way that is not vastly more complex than just using an exe to load your dll.)

Comment: @RoyiNamir - It is not that difficult to create an `exe` that just called the DLL.

Comment: @oded you right. I just wanted to understand the reason why it is not working. ( although it is pretty strange since my dll is does inherit the appropriate namespaces and has onStart and OnStop methods...guess i need clean exe file....but it makes sence in a matter of an Entry Point which DLL does NOT have)