# Visual Studio Prevent Changes to Linked File

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio you can add a link to a source file in another project.  Is there a way to enforce preventing any changes from being performed on the linked source file (ie: link them into a project as 'read only', so as to prevent accidental modifications by folks who don't realize they are linked, and not local to the project)?

I have two projects, one of which is a DLL, the other is an EXE.  The DLL contains a Windows ServiceInstaller and ServiceBase classes.  I link these classes into my EXE (there are multiple flavors of the EXE) from the DLL in order for the EXE to be installable as a service and for me to not have to replicate the ServiceBase and ServiceInstaller in all of the EXEs.  I do not however want to inadvertently be able to make changes to the linked classes from within the context of the EXE project.

Comment: Is there a reason you are linking the source file rather than referencing the assembly?

Comment: @nintendojunkie - Yes, as I mentioned in my question, the source files are the ServiceBase and the ServiceInstaller;  these files are required to run/start a service.

Comment: Gotcha - I forgot that the service base and installers have to be present in the executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not via some Visual Studio-supported mechanism, no.

IMHO, as a general rule you should not be using a linked file like that. Yes, the feature exists in VS, but for the very reason you mention as well as others, it's a great way to create code maintenance headaches.

Note that your own scenario could be just as easily solved by exposing shared types in an assembly and referencing that assembly from those that need them. I.e. just reference the DLL from your EXE and use the types as compiled into the DLL rather than having the EXE define new versions of the types using the same source code.

Comment: The types in question are the ServiceInstaller and Service classes; they cannot be exposed and referenced from the EXE since a Windows Service [is not startable from a DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362514/net-windows-service-from-dll). The only way I could think of sharing these types across all of my EXEs was via the link mechanism into the EXE.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not understanding. If a type is in a DLL, it can be exposed from that DLL (assuming you have control over the source of the type, which it seems you do). Yes, you can't run a service straight from a DLL (unless hosted by an .exe of course...Windows does this for other services), but that doesn't impose any restrictions on what's _in_ the DLL, nor in what other assemblies can _use_ from the DLL. Just as any .NET .exe (including services) relies on DLLs like mscorlib.dll, System.dll, etc., so too can your .NET service use service-related types from a DLL.

Comment: If you look at the ServiceInstaller and Service objects Visual Studio adds when you create a Windows Service, you will see a total of three files for each one; a .cs, a Designer.cs and a .resx.  You are absolutely correct on referencing types from an external DLL, but based on how these two objects work, it really is not possible.  Perhaps the best way to illustrate my problem would be to have you create a Windows Service and Class Library in Visual Studio. Move the ServiceInstaller and Service objects out of the Windows Service EXE and into the Class library.

Comment: But you can change accessibility for types, making them public from the assembly. And even if that weren't possible, you can always wrap the types in public types.

Comment: If you could please give it a try and let me know if it works for you, I would appreciate it.  I think you will find that while the project may compile, attempting to access the derived objects in the EXE will cause Visual Studio 2013 to blow a gasket.  Keep in mind, it is not just a class we are talking about here, but a designer file and a resource.  Thanks for your thoughts on the topic however!

Comment: I did try it, and it works fine. As noted in the other answer, your EXE still needs public classes inheriting the actual installer and service classes in your DLL. But this is as simple as `[RunInstaller(true)] public class ExeProjectInstaller : ProjectInstaller { }` where the actual `ProjectInstaller` class is in your DLL. Likewise the service is something like `public class ExeService1 : Service1 { }`

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does not have a way to set a "read-only" attribute for a linked file, but in general, linked files cause more problems than they solve.

Generally speaking, the preferred method for code reuse is to put the classes into a DLL and then reference those classes from the EXE - but in your case, the ServiceInstaller and ServiceBase classes have to be present in the EXE in order for the Windows service mechanism to pick them up.

Instead of linking the files, you could create base classes that inherit from ServiceInstaller and ServiceBase and put those in the DLL.  Then add new classes into the EXE that inherit from your custom base class (which contains most of the logic).  This way, all of the shared code gets pulled in from the shared DLL, but the EXE(s) still contain the classes necessary for the Windows service to start.

Comment: See my comments in Peter's answer regarding these classes.

Comment: I'm working on a project where we have done this with a few windows services.  We're using VS2012, but I wouldn't think it would be different for VS2013.  Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: Yes - when one attempts to double click on the derived ServiceInstaller or Service classes, the designer blows a gasket because the resource file is not present.

Comment: "blows a gasket" is neither precise nor useful. What is the exact error text? If VS is saying that a file is not present, why isn't that file present? Where are you double-clicking on the derived `ServiceInstaller` and `ServiceBase` classes, and why?

Comment: Here is what I tried: I changed the access modifiers on the Service and ServiceInstaller in the DLL to public.  I then went and derived from these classes in my EXE.  In Solution Explorer, the icon for the ServiceInstaller and Service classes within the EXE changed to the 'Service Component' (document with three small squares in the bottom left corner).  When I attempt to double click on the Service I get the following error: `Constructor on type 'BaseDll.ServiceClassName' not found.`

Comment: The stack trace in Visual Studio 2013 shows: `at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)`.  You are correct in that the compiled EXE will function properly as a service, but the designer is not usable.